# _safeMint not found or not visible

Tags: solidity

I have smart contract which takes care for multiple ERC721 smart contracts, additionally I have function which mint nft from a one of the ERC721 created by the contract but when i call:

```
ERC721(collectionAddress)._safeMint(msg.sender, 1);
```

I hit following error:

```
Member "_safeMint" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract ERC721.
```

Any idea how to fix it? :S

[image]

Answer (score 3):

_safeMint is usually an internal/private function, so you don't have access to it from your external CollectionManager contract.

(Additionally, the ERC721 interface does not contain a "mint" function.)

If you are in control of the ERC721 contracts you take care of, you can add a function and call it from CollectionManager:

```
function mint(address _to, uint _amount) external {
    require(msg.sender == address(collectionManager));
    _safeMint(_to, _amount);
}
```